# Rails 3 question - locking row for specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, locking, sqlite

I'm building a rails 3 app in which it sells a limited number of items. I'm looking for a way to hold an item for a specific amount of time so that when someone selects an item, they have time to purchase it before someone else can purchase it before them. I have done some research as to row locking but haven't found a usable method thus far for specifying a time.

Thanks for any help or ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical workflow pattern, where you acquire an object for a duration. You can achieve this easily by implementing application level locks.

1) Add lock fields to the model.

```
locker_id
lock_until
```

2) Now you can implement this logic in the Product model.

```
class Product

  belongs_to :locker, :class_name => "User",
           :condition => lambda { {:conditions => ["lock_until < ? ", Time.now]}}

  def locked?
    !lock_until.nil? and lock_until > Time.now
  end

  def lock_for_duration(usr, duration=10.minutes)
    return false if locked?
    self.locker_id = user.id
    self.lock_until = duration.from_now
    self.save   
  end

  def release_lock
    return true unless locked?
    self.locker_id = nil
    self.lock_until = nil
    self.save    
  end
end
```

Here is how to use this:

```
usr = User.first
product.lock_for_duration(usr, 30.minutes)
product.locked?
product.locker?
```

Comment: These of course assume that each Product is exactly one item, having no seperate quantity or inventory. For that you'd need a seperate Locked-Product model, with each Product having many transitory locked-product rows, each having a specific count.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was sort of what I was thinking but not for sure how to implement. I should have given more information before but what would you suggest as for the individual items. The application is for selling seats for an event, should i create a row for each seat (which could result in quite a few rows, ha) or would it be better to check for available seats dynamically then lock the seat in a separate table until sold (or released)? Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting a `locked_until` timestamp that's checked whenever someone attempts to buy one of these items. If there are no items with a `locked_until` time in the past, then all items are "sold out". For actual selling of the items, I would have a `sold` boolean field.